# Flipping UIViews (like new Text Books flash cards)

Tags: ios5

How to implement the iOS 5 flipping effect on a view like the one from Apple's new text book study cards?

Here you can see it working (min 2:56): http://www.apple.com/education/#video-textbooks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CoreAnimation, layer based. There's no standard flip animations like that, at least yet.

Comment: Are simple effect like the UIView transitions part of the Core Animation framework?

Comment: If you mean page curl/flip effect like in UIPageViewController, then probably no, I think OpenGL involved.